Custom guitar item not producing noise Forge 1.20.1 Java
I'm still very new to the Minecraft modding scene, and I'm trying to create a guitar that when right-clicked within the players hand, plays a short .ogg. The issue is that while the game and items load in, nothing occurs when right-clicked. No use animation, and more importantly no noise.
Here is the code I have right now for calling the sound:
@Override
public InteractionResultHolder<ItemStack> use(Level pLevel, Player pPlayer, InteractionHand pUsedHand) {
    pLevel.playSound(null, pPlayer.getX(), pPlayer.getY(), pPlayer.getZ(), ModSounds.GUITAR_STRUMMED.get(), SoundSource.PLAYERS, 1f, 1.f);
    return super.use(pLevel, pPlayer, pUsedHand);
}

And here is the code for the sounds itself:
{
  "guitar_stummed": {
    "subtitles": "sounds.learningmod.guitar_strummed",
    "sounds": [
      "learningmod:guitar_strummed",
      "learningmod:guitar_strummedb"
    ]
  }
}

And for creating its registry:
public class ModSounds {
    public static final DeferredRegister<SoundEvent> SOUND_EVENTS =
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.SOUND_EVENTS, LearningMod.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<SoundEvent> GUITAR_STRUMMED = registerSoundEvents("guitar_strummed");

    private static RegistryObject<SoundEvent> registerSoundEvents(String name) {
        return SOUND_EVENTS.register(name, () -> SoundEvent.createVariableRangeEvent(new ResourceLocation(LearningMod.MOD_ID, name)));
    }

    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus){
        SOUND_EVENTS.register(eventBus);
    }

At first I tried changing the @Override to a useon to see if forcing it to a block would give a consistent trigger for it, but that went nowhere as I didn't have the variables for even filling out the command. I tried shifting the order of the registry to see if there was a conflict I wasn't seeing, but that didn't help. Got rid of the second SFX, yet nothing changed. So far everything I've tried was a dud, and the guitar has absolutely no functionality.
In truth, I have been following a tutorial, so while I understand the code itself, I'm ignorant to many functions or exceptions that weren't shown to me.
